# Format in SQL - Decimal to Integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I format the below Decimal to Integer

```
Input = 999.11
Output = 0099900
```

Logic is like, the decimals has to be as Zeros and the length should be within the Max(7) for which i have to add the leading Zeros

Comment: You CANNOT add leading zeros to a number. The only way to accomplish this is to generate a string. Is that REALLY what you want to do? Think about how you intend to use this value. And do you want to truncate the value or round it before "conversion"?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense as written because integers (and numbers in general) do not have leading zeros.  You seem to want a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select FORMAT(cast(999.11 as int) * 100, '0000000')
```